# Replicação de banco de dados

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, postgresql, replicação

já li alguns artigos referente a replicação de banco de dados e espelhamento, mas uma dúvida que ainda tenho, e não encontrei uma resposta "concreta" seria referente e atualização do banco.

Por exemplo: Tenho o MASTER e o SLAVE, vou implementar uma nova funcionalidade no meu sistema e precisa adicionar novas tabelas, ou atualizar tabelas já existentes, adicionando novos campos ou removendo, entre outras operações necessárias.

Se eu atualizar o master, essas alterações em tabelas serão replicadas também para o slave?

Ou se eu fizesse essa atualização no slave (supondo que a replicação seja bidirecional), também seria replicada para o master?

Hoje, supondo que esse seja mesmo o processo...É a maneira utilizada para realizar essas atualizações em campos das tabelas, sem que a aplicação fique indisponível?

Comment: Provavelmente vai ter que deixar algum software para sincronizar, talvez uma rotina com CRONTAB. De qualquer forma é um assunto muito amplo. Não posso afirmar que este seja o caminho ideal, nem a sua ideia que descreveu nem a ideia de sincronizar.

Comment: Sim, compreendo essa questão....Mas minha dúvida seria, esses softwares vão sincronizar tudo, além dos dados?

Comment: Não tem software pronto pra isto (quero dizer deve ter), mas no geral usando as ferramentas nativas do MYSQL-client **você mesmo** define o que deseja sincronizar, fazendo um full-backup (deve ter maneira mais fácil) e fazendo um drop do slave.

Comment: Entendi, é, até o momento, eram essas as possibilidades que eu já tinha visto pessoas comentando....Realmente é um assunto amplo e complexo. Agradeço a reposta, caso eu encontrar mais algo interessante, irei compartilhar.

Comment: Eu uso SymmetricDS, faz todo o trabalho duro sem problemas, e pode usar qualquer banco de dados e ainda pode usar bancos diferentes nos servidores.
Funciona muito bem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cada método de replicação possui seus prós e contras. Como dito nos comentários da pergunta, você precisa identificar as suas necessidades para encontrar então o esquema de replicação mais adequado para sua aplicação.

Segue abaixo, em linhas gerais, transcrição do "discurso" que sempre utilizo quando preciso entrar nesse assunto. Foco em PostgreSQL, que é a solução que mais utilizo diariamente e com a qual possuo mais afinidade.

#### Replicação unidirecional

O PostgreSQL oferece de forma nativa apenas o método de replicação unidirecional, em que há um servidor *master* e um ou mais servidores *slave* em *standby*. Os servidores em *standby* podem ser utilizados para queries de consulta, mas não de escrita, sendo chamados nesse caso de [***hot standby***](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hot-standby.html). Nesse modo de replicação, todas as alterações efetuadas no *master* serão feitas também, automaticamente, em todos os servidores *slave*.

O método de replicação mais básico, que não oferece suporte a *queries* de leitura nos servidores *standby* é chamado de [***log shipping***, ou ***warm standby***](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/warm-standby.html). Nesse método, segmentos de log de transação do Postgres (*WAL*- *write-ahead log*), de 16MB cada, são enviados pela rede para os servidores de réplica e executados em processo cíclico. Dado o tempo para "preenchimento" de um segmento desses, este método de replicação representa certa lentidão no processo de replicação, sendo recomendado para baixos volumes de dados ou para circunstâncias em que não é necessário que o sincronismo da réplica seja tão atualizado.

Além do *log shipping*, o PostgreSQL possui um modo chamadao ***streaming replication***, em que um fluxo constante de alterações é enviado diretamente ao servidor *slave* através de conexão persistente. Isso permite constante checagem da integridade dos dados aplicados e, portanto, o referido *hot standby*.

A replicação em *hot standby* pode ser configurada tanto como *assíncrona* (o padrão), em que os dados podem levar algum tempo para ser escritos nos servidores *slave*, quanto *síncrona*, em que o `COMMIT` do usuário só é considerado completamente atendido quando for efetuado também no servidor *slave*. É possível configurar um ambiente misto de réplicas tanto síncronas quanto assíncronas, assíncronas em cascata etc.

Embora o uso de replicação síncrona para fins de alta disponibilidade seja tentador, deve-se ter em mente a relação entre capacidade de transferência de rede e o volume de dados replicados. Se sua rede for lenta, os comandos de alteração executados no *master* demorarão para ser `COMMIT`ados e o banco parecerá "travado". Arquiteturas para replicação síncrona de boa performance tendem a ser especificadas com o uso de cabos *cross* máquinas vizinhas, sem qualquer outro ativo intermediário de rede, para evitar gargalos. Mesmo assim, grandes volumes de dados trafegados tendem a inviabilizar tal nível de imediatez. O custo de infraestrutura, portanto, aumenta de acordo com o volume transacional da aplicação, até se tornar inviável em quadros de alto volume de dados.

Dito isso, configurações de replicação que utilizam o método de *hot standby* representam o mundo intermediário: a replicação continua *assíncrona*, mas o volume de dados trafegados permite que as atualizações aconteçam de forma quase síncrona (*near-sync*), o que aparenta ser suficiente para a maioria dos usos sem risco de incorrer nas interrupções do método síncrono.

---

#### Replicação bidirecional

Não há solução nativa de replicação bidirecional em PostgreSQL, sendo necessário instalar *plugins* que ofereçam tal funcionalidade. O mais estável e mais utilizado atualmente é chamado [BDR, desenvolvido pela 2nd Quadrant](http://bdr-project.org/docs/stable/). Entende-se que em algum estágio tais funcionalidades serão incorporadas pela base de código do PostgreSQL, mas por enquanto é necessária a instalação do *plugin* BDR à parte.

Como o nome indica, a replicação bidirecional permite que sejam efetuadas alterações em todos os servidores envolvido, sendo portando um método de replicação ***multimaster***. Alterações simultâneas de um mesmo objeto em nós diferentes podem provocar conflitos a serem resolvidos pelo *plugin*, e tal processo de resolução pode ser custoso. Isso significa que a aplicação deve estar preparada e dimensionada para evitar ao máximo tais tipos de conflito.

A replicação BDR é inerentemente lógica, oferecendo a funcionalidade de configuração dos objetos a serem replicados. Dessa forma, tabelas temporárias e outros dados menos importantes podem ser deixados de fora da replicação, podendo reduzir o custo com resolução de conflitos e o tempo de processamento das alterações pelos nós que recebem os dados.

Outra característica do BDR é ser inerentemente assíncrono: o `COMMIT` é retornado para o usuário pelo nó em que este comandou a alteração, e os demais nós terão a transação aplicada algum tempo no futuro. A replicação por BDR utiliza o mesmo mecanismo de *streaming replication* supracitado, portanto tendendo a resultar, quando não há necessidade de resolver conflitos, em tempos de replicação considerados *near-sync*.

A criação e configuração de nós bidirecionais, a manutenção e a monitoração da qualidade da replicação tendem a demandar mais atenção e trabalho do que os métodos de replicação unidirecional. Isso é algo que se deve levar em conta na escolha do BDR.

---

#### Balanceamento, paralelismo e pool de conexões

Há outros métodos de trabalho que podem solucionar problemas sem que seja necessário recorrer à replicação. Ferramentas que ficam entre a aplicação e o PostgreSQL, como o [PgBouncer](https://pgbouncer.github.io/), permitem a divisão de trabalho entre mais de um servidor de banco de dados até no nível do comando em si, possibilitando um particionamento lógico de dados entre nós. O [Pgpool-II](http://www.pgpool.net/mediawiki/index.php/Main_Page) permite a formação de *pools* de conexão entre nós, balanceamento de carga e execução paralela de *queries* em mais de um servidor. Ele também pode ser utilizado como agente intermediário em esquemas de *failover* automático.

Tais tecnologias podem ser utilizadas sozinhas ou em conjunto com métodos de replicação. Às vezes o que sua aplicação precisa é apenas de um Pgpool-II mandando as mesmas *queries* para dois bancos diferentes: o momento da execução em ambos os lados pode diferir em questão de milissegundos, *trata-se de transações diferentes*, mas os dados existem dos dois lados.

Além dessas duas ferramentas há outras capazes desse tipo de malabarismo, cada uma com suas funcionalidades específicas.

---

#### Casos de uso

Como visto acima, cada método de replicação oferece uma relação "custo-benefício" diferente para o sistema. Antes de se adotar uma solução, deve-se ter em mente as necessidades específicas da aplicação. Segue alguns quadros típicos.

- Você replica para garantir a disponibilidade em momentos de mudança?
  Talvez efetuar um *failover* para um nó *hot standby* assíncrono em momentos de
  menor fluxo transacional seja suficiente. Se houver momento em que o volume de transações zere por mais tempo, até mesmo um *warm standby* daria conta, só que sem a vantagem de ter um nó separado só para consultas.
- O problema é garantir que nenhum dado seja perdido em caso de
  desastre? Bom, se *absolutamente* nenhum dado pode ser perdido, talvez seu sistema seja candidato à replicação síncrona, mas isso pode ter impacto na velocidade de atendimento das transações pelo banco. Ironicamente, se o sincronismo total não impacta sua aplicação, talvez a replicação assíncrona também atenda sem problemas!
- Seu objetivo maior é dividir a demanda dos clientes entre vários servidores de forma a atender com mais agilidade? Isso é um trabalho para a replicação bidirecional! Lembrando que em um ambiente centralizado tende a ser rara a necessidade de mais de um servidor de escrita, e não se deve esquecer que o *overhead* de manutenção tende a ser maior do que nos outros modos de replicação.

É também sempre bom ressaltar a importância de efetuar *backups* periódicos de seus dados, mantidos apartados de seus sistemas de produção, para recuperação em caso de desastres maiores. A replicação pode ser entendida como um *backup online*, mas ela não de protege de falhas humanas, como um `DROP` ou `TRUNCATE` feitos no momento errado!

---

#### Referências

Segue algumas referências sobre replicação com PostgreSQL:

- [PostgreSQL.org - Chapter 26. High Availability, Load Balancing, and Replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/high-availability.html) (documentação)
- [BDR - Documentação](http://bdr-project.org/docs/stable/index.html) (destaque para a seção de monitoração)
- [PostgreSQL Wiki - Replication, Clustering, and Connection Pooling](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling) (compara ferramentas análogas, às mencionadas nesta resposta)
- [PostgreSQL Wiki - Replicação multimaster](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Multimaster)
- [PostgreSQL.org - Chapter 25. Backup and Restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/backup.html)

Comment: Show de bola @nunks.lol , consegui sanar minhas dúvidas com sua explicação, estarei dando uma olhada nas referências que você disponibilizou! Fico agradecido.

Comment: @Marcelolx fico contende de poder ajudar. Provavelmente vou editar essa resposta aos poucos, melhorando aqui e ali, para poder indicar para as pessoas quando me perguntarem sobre isso no trabalho também, haha. Só frisando que tudo o que eu falei é pra PostgreSQL, não conheço as soluções de replicação em MySQL pra poder falar com propriedade.

Comment: Sim, eu também estava a procura de uma solução relacionada ao PostgreSQL...só incluí o MySQL nas tags, para caso alguém conhecer uma solução interessante para o mesmo.